# How do I reset the settings of an app that only shows in the menu bar? (Chatty - facebook messenger)

Tags: macos, applications, menu-bar, facebook

My problem is that I toggled a setting which told the app to only show in the menu bar but now I can't access the settings at all. I want to reset the settings for the Chatty mac app but I can't find out how to do this. I have reached out to the developer too but I've not had a response as of yet.

I have tried right clicking and all sorts of alt, cmd and shift combinations on the menu bar icon yet nothing comes up like any other app.
I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling but it remembers my settings and also my login information. 
Lastly I tried looking for a settings file in **Library\Application Support** etc but cannot seem to find anything.

If anyone has any ideas I would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard hotkey for accessing an app's preferences/settings is <kbd>⌘</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd>.

Please test this to see if it solved your problem.